# Looping through python code

Tags: python, loops, nested, nested-loops

I have a python script which searches a web page for information. currently I add the search term as a parameter when i run my program 'myscript.py searchterm'.

What I would like to do is to have a file with my search terms in, get my script to loop through each one in turn on its own.

so I would populate my list from a file like this....

```
with open('mylist.txt', 'r') as f:
    searchterms = f.readlines()
```

I already have my code which looks something like this...just to give you an idea of layout...

```
counter = 0
try:
    while counter <10:

    #do some other stuff here

    counter=counter+10

except IOError:
    print "No result found!"+""
```

I need to wrap this in another loop to do this for every item in my list and I'm failing.

I know I need to reset the counter if it gets to 10, move onto my next list item and loop through the above but I don't know how.
I find the python docs difficult to understand and I would appreciate a little help.

TIA

Comment: This is very unclear. What's the point of the counter? Why do you need to increase it by 10 each time?

Comment: because it gets 10 results every time the web page is searched which is all i need if i posted the entire code you would understand but i'm not willing to do that at the moment.

Comment: I just need to perform the above code for each one of my list items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of search terms, you can easily loop through them and pass them to your existing loop like:

```
for searchterm in searchterms:   
    counter = 0
    try:
        while counter <10:

        #do some other stuff here with searchterm

        counter=counter+10

    except IOError:
        print "No result found!"+""
```

Be sure that your counter correctly resets at the beginning of each search term's loop.